# Sequelizejs: how to use transactions along with raw queries

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm using sequelize orm. I cannot find in their documentation how to use transactions when using raw queries. All I see there is for model defined query methods. But for raw queries, there is no specification on where to put the transaction object to use for that specific query.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[query method docs](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/sequelize.js%7ESequelize.html#instance-method-query)

You can pass the transaction in as such:

```js
const t = await sequelize.transaction();

sequelize.query('SELECT * FROM table;', { transaction: t })
```

See [transactions docs](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/transactions.html) for different ways to define transactions.

Comment: They've restructured the docs. Details now at https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#instance-method-query

Answer (score 5):

The link above does not help me, but have figure out the solution:
(If you rollback in the catch block, the transaction will be reverted.)

```js
  sequelize.transaction(async transaction => {
    try {
      await sequelize.query(
        `
        UPDATE Balances
        SET amount = @amount := amount - ${10}
        WHERE userId=${1}`,
        {
          type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.UPDATE,
          transaction,
          raw: true
        },
      )

      await sequelize.query(
        `
        UPDATE Balances
        SET amount = @amount := amount - ${10}
        WHERE userId=${2}`,
        {
          type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.UPDATE,
          transaction,
          raw: true
        },
      )

    } catch (error) {
      transaction.rollback();
      throw `TRANSACTION_ERROR`;
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

Those who are still checking it out, use this:
We need to commit the transaction in the end.

```js
const t = await sequelize.transaction();

try{
  await sequelize.query('SELECT * FROM table;', { transaction: t })
  await t.commit();
}
catch (e) {
 await t.rollback();
}
```

Please check the documentation here: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/transactions.html

Answer (score 0):

```js
let t = db.transaction();
await db.sequelize.query(query, {
    type: QueryTypes.INSERT,
    // Use transaction in the object just after query 
    transaction: t,
    replacements: {},
});
```